# Laravel path not returning right view

Tags: laravel, path, redirect

I am new to Laravel. I am using **Iaravel 5.7**. I have a Laravel application where static website content can be changed from admin panel.

If user wants to access the admin panel he needs to login first;
means if user types `www.example.com/admin/` and user is already logged in then it's ok to go inside admin panel but if user is not logged in then he will be redirected to `www.example.com/admin/login` page.

Till here all redirection are working fine from controller; but problem starts here..

If user accesses admin panel by typing `www.example.com/admin/`, this url returns `404 error` and if user types `www.example.com/admin/admin/` this url returns me correct results that I wanted to see. I don't understand why it is happening. All my admin views are under `resources/views/admin/` folder.

My routes file (web.php)

```
Route::get('/', 'todocontroller@index');
Route::get('about', 'todocontroller@about');
Route::get('career', 'todocontroller@career');
Route::get('contact', 'todocontroller@contact');

// for admin panel

Route::group(array('prefix' => 'admin'), function()
    {
Route::get('/', 'adminController@index');
Route::get('login', 'adminController@getLoginPage');
Route::post('login', 'adminController@login');

});
```

`todocontroller.php` controller file

```
 public function index() { 
        $homepages=home_page::where('slider','1')->orderBy('position')->get(); 
        $aboutContent=about_page::find(1); 
        $whatWeDo=home_page::where('s_heading','!=','')->selectRaw('count(*) AS cnt, s_heading')->groupBy('s_heading')->first(); 

        $whatWe=home_page::where('s_heading','!=','')->get(); 

       return view('index',compact('homepages','aboutContent','whatWeDo','whatWe'));
     }
```

My controller file (`adminController.php`)

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Validator;

class adminController extends Controller
{
    public function index(){
        if(request()->hasCookie('user_id')){
              return view('admin.index');
        }else{
              return redirect('admin/login');
        }
    }


     public function getLoginPage(){
        return view('admin.login');
     }
}
```

Any help from you guys will be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: your route is correct bt i don't understand what u want

Comment: when i am typing www.example.com/admin/admin/ i am getting results that i expected but i want that results on www.example.com/admin/ this url. This url showing me 404 error. i have my all admin views on views/admin/ folder. I don't understand why it's happening

Comment: show ur todocontroller@index method

Comment: that method doesn't giving me any error. but for i'll show it up

Comment: public function index()
    {
     $homepages=home_page::where('slider','1')->orderBy('position')->get();
     $aboutContent=about_page::find(1);
     $whatWeDo=home_page::where('s_heading','!=','')->selectRaw('count(*) AS cnt, s_heading')->groupBy('s_heading')->first();
     $whatWe=home_page::where('s_heading','!=','')->get();
      return view('index',compact('homepages','aboutContent','whatWeDo','whatWe'));
    }